# Windows Command Prompt sudo?

Tags: windows, command-line, sudo, runas

I bounce between Linux and Windows and I am constantly in need of a sudo type command. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Just sharing info. I self answered below. I changed the title of the post to reflect this.

Comment: phrase the title and question as a question, *then* self answer in an answer. It is confusing to read like this. Also this seems like a duplicate, did you try searching before posting?

Comment: Shuffled everything around to make it less confusing. There are other questions about Windows and "Sudo" however, they just mention the runas command. Which my answer does make use of, but it echos it to sudo.bat in the system32 directory so instead of needing to type the whole command out they can just type sudo and their command to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work as a systems analyst for a small county and I am constantly switching between Windows and Linux. For the most part, not to bad. However, I am constantly running into issues with ls and sudo. After a little googlefu I found [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362692/how-to-create-ls-in-windows-command-prompt) which helped setting up an "ls" command.

```
echo dir %* > %systemroot%\system32\ls.bat
```

*(Courtesy of secghost and Vartan Simonian)*

Using that one liner I also wrote the following:

```
echo runas ^/noprofile ^/user:<domain>^\<username> ^"cmd /k ^%cd:~0,2^% ^& cd ^%cd^% ^& ^%*^" > %systemroot%\system32\sudo.bat
```

Run this in an elevated command prompt. Replace  with your domain or computer name and  with the username of an admin account you have access to.

Running the sudo command in the future will prompt for the admin password and place you in your current directory. Running sudo  will also run that command. EX: **sudo del test.file**

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is no `sudo` equivalent in Windows.  There is no way from a normal command prompt to run a command with elevated privileges.  The only thing you can do is make sure you always run your command prompt elevated.

Answer (score 0):

ConEmu console application for Windows has nice feature to create new console with elevated admin rights, keeps current directory also: https://conemu.github.io/en/LaunchNewTab.html)

Scripts:

```
 # create elavated admin console
conemu64.exe -cmd cmd -new_console:a

# inside elevated shell echo the sudo script for powershell 
echo "powershell -new_console:a" > c:\windows\sudo.ps1
# for powershell Core:
echo "pwsh -new_console:a" > c:\windows\sudo.ps1
```

now anywhere in ConEmu console from powershell you can type

```
sudo
```

Script sudo.cmd for cmd.exe shell is NOT WORKING, sorry...

```
echo "ConEmu64.exe -new_console:a" > c:\windows\sudo.cmd
```